# Codename One Eliminate Space around Chart

Tags: graph, codenameone, margin

I have an Android App and am using the Chart API for the first time.

My PIeGraph is located inside a Container in a Dialog, and when it's displayed, there is a large space around the graph, that I can't seem to get rid of.

[image] [image]

I have already played with all sorts of layouts and margin/ padding adjustments, but to no avail.

Any idea of how I can improve the result? My aim is to have minimal space at the top and mainly the bottom.

Here is my code:

```
class ClassFeedback {

    private Container containerDialog = new Container(new BorderLayout());
    Container containerGraph = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    private Dialog dialogExplain = new Dialog(new BorderLayout());

    public void dialogFinal () throws IOException {

        dialogExplain.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, containerDialog);
        containerDialog.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, containerGraph);

        // doesn't influence the space around the graph
        containerGraph.getAllStyles().setPadding(0,0,0,0);

        createPieChartForm();

        dialogExplain.show();

    }


    public void createPieChartForm() {

            int porcCor = cor* 100/ total ;
            int porcFal = fal *100 / total;

            double[] values = new double[]{porcFal, porcCor};
            int[] colors = new int[]{ColorUtil.BLUE, 0x009933};

            DefaultRenderer renderer = buildCategoryRenderer(colors);
            renderer.setDisplayValues(true);
            renderer.setShowLabels(true);

            // doesn't influence the space around the graph
            renderer.setMargins(new int [] {0,0,0,0});

            SimpleSeriesRenderer r = renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(0);
            r.setHighlighted(true);

            PieChart chart = new PieChart(buildCategoryDataset("Project budget", values), renderer);
            ChartComponent c = new ChartComponent(chart);

            // adding the chart to container with the BoxLayout
            containerGraph.add(c);

     }

    protected CategorySeries buildCategoryDataset(String title, double[] values) {
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(title);

            String[] strings = new String[]{"Errado %", "Certo %"};

            for (int i = 0 ; i != values.length ; i++) {
                series.add(strings[i], values[i]);
            }

            return series;

    }

    private DefaultRenderer buildCategoryRenderer(int[] colors) {
            DefaultRenderer renderer = new DefaultRenderer();
            renderer.setLabelsTextSize(40);
            renderer.setShowLegend(false);

            // doesn't influence the space around the graph
            renderer.setMargins(new int[]{20, 20, 120, 20});
            for (int color : colors) {
                SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
                r.setColor(color);
                renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);

            }
            return renderer;
     }

}
```

Comment: Did you try using `zoomTo` to increase the zoom of the chart?

Comment: That's for the graph, right? Tried it now with all sorts and sizes of doubles .. doesn't make a difference, unfortunately.

Comment: I have opened a separate project with the code from the example here https://www.codenameone.com/blog/codename-one-charts.html . The resulting picture from the simulation I have added to my question above. As you can see, there is a large gap between the graph and the legend below. The margins to the sides are also quite notable. Changing the values for margins and adding zoomTo didn't cause any difference, whatsoever. Neither did changing the layout from BorderLayout to BoxLayout.Y or X. I hope this helps to clarify the issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, you're referring to `setMargins` of the renderer right?
I'm not sure if there's too much to be done here. If the component has room to grow the drawing logic can place the legend where it wants. I doubt this is fixable without going deep into the chart rendering logic.

Comment: I have refined my model with the settings of the margins of the container where the graph is in. Increasing the margins below the container pushes the sides closer to the graph. That worked out pretty good. Surprisingly, zoomTo and adjusting the margins of the graph didn't have any impact.